# com.motorola.blur.home.ACTION_WIDGET_ADDED causes my AppWidgetProvider to stop responding?

Tags: android, android-widget

I've created a home screen widget by extending the AppWidgetProvider. It works fine on all phones tested so far except Motorola's Droid 2 from Verizon. It's running Android 2.2. What I noticed is when my widget is first place onto a homescreen it works for about +/- 15 seconds. Then I see the widget receives the action com.motorola.blur.home.ACTION_WIDGET_ADDED and the widget stops responding? The buttons on the widget still show pressed or selected states but the widget code itself is no longer called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else gets stuck on this the answer is [here](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/com-motorola-blur-home-ACTION-WIDGET-ADDED-makes-widget-stop/m-p/7772/highlight/false#M1569)

Basically, whenever you update your widget's remote views you have to re-register all pending intents.